# Invoking Pylint programmatically

Tags: python, automated-tests, pylint

I'd like to invoke the Pylint checker, limited to the error signalling part, as part of my unit testing. So I checked the Pylint executable script, got to the `pylint.lint.Run` helper class and there I got lost in a quite long `__init__` function, ending with a call to `sys.exit()`.

Anybody ever tried and managed to do so?

The dream-plan would be this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import pylint.lint
  pylint.lint.something(__file__, justerrors=True)
  # now continue with unit testing
```

Any hints? Other than "copy the `__init__` method and skip the `sys.exit()`", I mean?

I don't **need** the tests to be run by Pylint, it might as well be `pyflakes` or other software: feel free to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take a look at the `pylint/epylint.py` file which contains *two* different ways to start Pylint programmatically.

You can also simply call

```
from pylint.lint import Run
Run(['--errors-only', 'myfile.py'])
```

for instance.

Comment: combined with previous answer.  and with slight modification: `pylint.lint.Run(['--errors-only', filename])`

Comment: is there a way to parse multiple files when invoking pylint programatically?

Comment: @gobliins: yes, simply append other file names to the list given as Run argument.

Comment: Why is this method so criminally undocumented? There's a whole depth of return values and options and I can't find any documentation online! :-(

Answer (score 24):

I got the same problem recently.
syt is right, `pylint.epylint` got several methods in there. However they all call a subprocess in which python is launched again. In my case, this was getting quite slow.

Building from  mcarans answer, and finding that there is a flag exit, I did the following

```
class WritableObject(object):
    "dummy output stream for pylint"
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
    def write(self, st):
        "dummy write"
        self.content.append(st)
    def read(self):
        "dummy read"
        return self.content
def run_pylint(filename):
    "run pylint on the given file"
    from pylint import lint
    from pylint.reporters.text import TextReporter
    ARGS = ["-r","n", "--rcfile=rcpylint"]  # put your own here
    pylint_output = WritableObject()
    lint.Run([filename]+ARGS, reporter=TextReporter(pylint_output), exit=False)
    for l in pylint_output.read():
        do what ever you want with l...
```

which is about 3 times faster in my case.
With this I have been going through a whole project, using full output to check each source file, point errors, and rank all files from their note.

Comment: Thank you, it works! Here is the code that parses the output and returns the rating (feel free to add to the answer, if you like): https://pastebin.com/Lta2cCB8

Comment: You an also use: pylint_output = pylint.testutils.TestReporter() and then get the results with test_reporter.finalize().strip().   Or even better, look at the implementation of 'TestReporter' and implement your own to handle structural messages.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of creating a WritableObject class we can use StringIO. StringIO contains write method.

```
import sys
try:
    from io import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO

stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StringIO()

ARGS = ["-r","n", "--rcfile=rcpylint"]
r = lint.Run(['../test.py']+ARGS, exit=False)

test = sys.stdout.getvalue()
sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = stdout

print (test.split('\n'))
```

Source:

- @cdarke 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36310187/4440675)
- @mad7777's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919648/4440675)

Comment: Exactly what I thought when I saw the previous answers. By why modifying `stdout` when you can specify a customer "reporter"?  I have provided such solution

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad I came across this. I used some of the answers here and some initiative to come up with:

```
# a simple class with a write method
class WritableObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
    def write(self, string):
        self.content.append(string)
pylint_output = WritableObject()

pylint = lint.Run(args, reporter=ParseableTextReporter(pylint_output), exit=False)
```

Args in the above is a list of strings eg. ["-r", "n", "myfile.py"]

Comment: I put a solution above, but I have since found that calling Pylint programatically this way is bad because Pylint uses imports which are cached. So if you edited the file you were linting, the changes would not be seen. If you are only running Pylint programmatically once against a single script, then this is probably ok.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE:
At some point `pylint` changed the interface.  The above examples need to replace `exit=False` with `do_exit=False`. (@mad7777, @amit-tripathi)

(Learned as per https://github.com/carsongee/pytest-pylint/issues/80)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wrapper I use to programmatically call pylint so I have a --fail-under arg to overwite the default pylint exit code (usefull for CI). This snippet was tested using pylint 2.3.1

```py
""" Execute pylint and fail if score not reached. """
import argparse
import sys
from pylint import lint

desc = "PyLint wrapper that add the --fail-under option."\
       " All other arguments are passed to pylint."
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc, allow_abbrev=False)
parser.add_argument('--fail-under', dest='threshold', type=float, default=8,
                    help='If the final score is more than THRESHOLD, exit with'
                    ' exitcode 0, and pylint\'s exitcode otherwise.')

args, remaining_args = parser.parse_known_args()

threshold = args.threshold

run = lint.Run(remaining_args, do_exit=False)
score = run.linter.stats['global_note']

if score < threshold:
    sys.exit(run.linter.msg_status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another entry point for pylint is the `epylint.py_run` function, that implement the stdout and stderr interception. However, as shown in the following code, pylint seems to not write its reports in stdout:

```
from pylint import epylint

pylint_stdout, pylint_stderr = epylint.py_run(__file__, return_std=True)
print(pylint_stdout.getvalue())  # -> there is just the final rank, no report nor message
print(pylint_stderr.getvalue())
```

Now, i found that pylint from API and pylint from CLI do not use the same default parameters. So, you just have to provides the parameters you need to pylint.

```
from pylint import epylint
options = '--enable=all'  # all messages will be shown
options += '--reports=y'  # also print the reports (ascii tables at the end)

pylint_stdout, pylint_stderr = epylint.py_run(__file__ + ' ' + options, return_std=True)
print(pylint_stdout.getvalue())
print(pylint_stderr.getvalue())
```

As described [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/1.7/pylint/epylint.py#L111), pylint will perform the parsing itself, and will correctly output the expected results in stdout.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers here have mentioned, `pylint.lint.Run` is the way to go, however, there is not a good demonstration of Python 3 specific uses. Also, `pylint` gives a useful reporter class that should be used to capture the output of a pylint run. There are options for all different output types. In the following examples, I'll capture the Colorized output using the `ColorizedTextReporter` class.

### As of pylint 2.12

```py
from pylint import lint
from pylint.reporters import text

# list of pylint args to only enable warnings, errors, and fatals
args = ["my_file.py", "--enable=W,E,F"]

pylint_output = StringIO() # need a StringIO object where the output will be stored
reporter = text.ColorizedTextReporter(pylint_output)

run = lint.Run(args, reporter=reporter, exit=False) # exit=False means don't exit when the run is over

score = run.lint.stats.global_note # pylint score out of 10

# also available are stats.error, stats.warnings, etc...
```

### Before pylint 2.12

The only difference is that the `stats` object of `Run().lint` is a dictionary. So you'd get the score by `run.lint.stats.get("global_note")`

Answer (score -1):

To get pylint report in python script see an example

```
from pylint import lint
from pylint.reporters import CollectingReporter
from dataclasses import asdict

report = CollectingReporter()
result = lint.Run([TOP_DIR], reporter=report, do_exit=False)

print("result ",result.linter.stats.global_note)

line_format = "{path}:{line}:{column}: {msg_id}: {msg} ({symbol})"
for error in report.messages:
    print(line_format.format(**asdict(error)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on few solutions here, I came with the following (mixing `StringIO` to avoid creating a "simple class" when something already exists) and the `TextReporter` from pylint:

```py
from io import StringIO
from pylint.lint import Run
from pylint.reporters.text import TextReporter

files =  ["my_file.py"]
pylint_options = ["--disable=line-too-long,import-error,fixme"]

pylint_output = StringIO()
Run(
    files + pylint_options,
    reporter=TextReporter(pylint_output),
    exit=False,
)

for line in pylint_output.getvalue().splitlines():
    ... # do something with each line, like filtering / extracting
```

You can also use `ParseableTextReporter` instead of `TextReporter` and the results will be slightly different (maybe easier to parse):

With `TextReporter`:

```
************* Module my_file
my_file.py:65:0: W0613: Unused argument 'args' (unused-argument)
my_file.py:65:0: W0613: Unused argument 'kwargs' (unused-argument)
my_file.py:90:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
my_file.py:93:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
my_file.py:96:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
my_file.py:99:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
my_file.py:102:4: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
my_file.py:183:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.61/10 (previous run: 9.61/10, +0.00)
```

With `ParseableTextReporter`:

```
************* Module my_file
my_file.py:65: [W0613(unused-argument), CoverageSummaryTable.__init__] Unused argument 'args'
my_file.py:65: [W0613(unused-argument), CoverageSummaryTable.__init__] Unused argument 'kwargs'
my_file.py:90: [C0116(missing-function-docstring), ProtoLogger.debug] Missing function or method docstring
my_file.py:93: [C0116(missing-function-docstring), ProtoLogger.info] Missing function or method docstring
my_file.py:96: [C0116(missing-function-docstring), ProtoLogger.warning] Missing function or method docstring
my_file.py:99: [C0116(missing-function-docstring), ProtoLogger.error] Missing function or method docstring
my_file.py:102: [C0116(missing-function-docstring), ProtoLogger.critical] Missing function or method docstring
my_file.py:183: [C0116(missing-function-docstring), coverage_output] Missing function or method docstring

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 9.61/10 (previous run: 9.61/10, +0.00)
```

It's up to you :)

Thanks to @mad7777, @Amit Tripathi, and @mcarans