# Pylint: discard cached file state

Tags: python, pylint

I use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7919648/1789574) to run pylint from PY script. (I use pylint plugin similar to SublimeLinter, but no new process of Python is used, Python is embedded into Windows program). I see that even if I change source file, ie fixed errors, pylint still gives old messages.

E.g. I opened source code in editor, I have function w/out docstring, pylint shows this error. Now I add docstring, save file (I don't restart editor), and call pylint-plugin again - but pylint still gives "no docstring" error.

Any way to have actual error messages without restarting editor with pylint plugin? Any way to tell pylint "discard file cache"?

Comment: I tried this. Before accessing pylint, i deleted pylint and "pylint.nnnnnnnnn" (if exist) from sys.modules. This doesn't give good, because on second access to pylint api, it gave empty result. I mean function from my URL, it gave empty pylint output if I did this. (It was only one place where i accessed pylint api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

astroid (pylint's underlying  library for AST) is holding a cache of ast per module. Try the code below to throw away the whole cache:

```
from astroid import MANAGER
MANAGER.astroid_cache.clear()
```

Relevant issue:
https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/158

Comment: can't open the link

Comment: the link is kind of pointless as it's just a copy of this SO thread and it got closed without any action taken. it's funny how pylint for some reason assumes that code never changes and thus the cache never gets cleared automatically. especially, since it is a _developer_ tool

Answer (score 2):

Using pylint in vscode on Windows with similar issues:

1. go to C:\Users[my username].pylint.d directory
2. delete the .stat files making problems
3. restart vscode
4. trigger pylint again

Note: In my case I renamed a file from uppercase to lowercase. Then I got the result