# Pylint API: `py_run` hangs up

Tags: python, pylint

I'm pylinting some python scripts using following pylint API:

`(out,err)= epylint.py_run(command_options=file , return_std=True, script='pylint')`

However I am surprised by the behaviour of `py_run`, it works fine for almost all scripts and gives normal std output message. However, for some scripts it hangs up, and doesn't respond at all. I investigated a little more, and found that `py_run` module opens an external process to execute pylint. There's a possibility of PIPE being clogged in my situation. I am not sure about my reason though. Please share if somebody have faced similar situation? or any info about an alternative API?

Comment: I faced the same situation, however no good idea how to fix it though...

Comment: However,  I found out that you may rather call the pylint Run instead. Here I found some tips : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028268/invoking-pylint-programmatically