# How to programmatically lint or check type hint the code string in python?

Tags: python, mypy, pylint

Currently I have a following format:

```
import pylint, mypy

# python code that I want to lint is in string
code = '
import pandas as pd
def foo(a:int, b:int)->int:
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    ...
'
```

I'm running the python using some software, and I can't run terminal command that would simply do `pylint ml_model.py`

I can get the code script as **string**.

So what i want is:

```
import pylint, mypy

# python code that I want to lint is in string
code = '
import pandas as pd
def foo(a:int, b:int)->int:
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    ...
'

# result would show the score and errors
result = pylint.lint(code)
```

I can't get the file directory, which if i did, i could use solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028268/invoking-pylint-programmatically)

I don't need to use pylint specifically, it can be anything.

Any hints or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you write to a file then run `pylint` as per your the solution you pointed out to?

Comment: i can't write to a file because i don't have enough permission to do so on SaaS that i'm working on